# How do I append values to ulab ndarray in micropython?

Tags: list, numpy, append, micropython

I want to append values to ulab array. ulab is numpy implementation in micropython.

I am reading values from ADC and I want to append these values to ulab array like we do in numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a = np.append(4,a)
```

I looked up documentation but I didnt find append method. Can any one help please?

Comment: If you plan to use this in a loop please use list instead. Besides, If there is no method `append`, then you can convert the array to a list, add an item and convert the array back in the worst case (not efficient though). Maybe you could try `np.concatenate` alternatively? Also note that it is `numpy.append(arr, values)` and not `numpy.append(values, arr)`.

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly conceived and named function in `numpy`.  It's `np.concatenate` made to look sort of like list append.

Comment: @hpaulj 

Thanks for your asnwers.
There is no method in ulab to append. The alternative method is called concatenate only available in later versions of ulab micropython module.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your asnwer. There is no method in ulab to append. The alternative method is called concatenate only available in later versions of ulab micropython module.